# Ajax timer, update panels and repeaters

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, updatepanel, repeater

I am facing a problem using a timer on a page with repeaters.

My page basically look like this : (Didn't write down all the labels and other non important stuff, the page is pretty big)

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" ID="UpdateTimer" />
<UpdatePanel 1>
<dropdownlist/>
<Panel 1>
    <TextBox/><Button/>
</Panel 1>

<Repeater 1> //Bound to a list in code behind
    <Checkbox/><textbox/>
</Repeater 1>
<Button/>

<Repeater 2> //Bound to a list in code behind
    <button/><button/>
</Repeater 2>

<Repeater 3> //Bound to a dataset in code behind
    <textbox/><button/><button/>
</Repeater 3>
<button/><button/><button/>
</UpdatePanel 1>
<panel 2>
   //Jscript stuff that doesn't change anything to my current problem.
</panel 2>
<UpdatePanel 2>
    <Image/>
</UpdatePanel 2>
```

In my page, I am trying to add a timer with 5000ms tick. The  OnTick event need to call my BindRepeater2 method since I just want to reload the repeater to show updated info.

 I tried placing the timer before the updatePanel, inside, after, in panel 1, in panel 2, in the repeater. I tried having multiple updatePanel for each repeaters, I tried placing panels everywhere... The best result I got was my textBox in Panel 1 not loosing the information inside it. The image in UpdatePanel2 always disapear (Since I bind it once on pageLoad if not postback) and the textboxes in repeater1 always reset themselves. On top of it, the OnTick event loose focus on my textboxes and leftclick when I browse my dropdownlist.

I'm out of ideas on how to fix this problem.

Edit : I found out that I can use ajax to build my repeater. But I have no clues how to do that. Anyone could explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **UpdateMode= "Conditional"** property to your UpdatePanel and in OnTick event after Binding your Repeater set `UpdatePanel1.update();`

---

**OnTick Event**

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindRepeater();
        UpdatePanel1.update();
    }
```

Comment: same still happens. My image disappear, the textboxes loose content and I loose focus.

Comment: I tweaked my code around a little and it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking around my page, I ended up with this.

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" ID="UpdateTimer" />
<UpdatePanel1 UpdateMode="Conditional">
<dropdownlist/>
<Panel 1>
    <TextBox/><Button/>
</Panel 1>
<Repeater 1> //Bound to a list in code behind
    <Checkbox/><textbox/>
</Repeater 1>
<Button/>
</UpdatePanel1>

<UpdatePanel2 UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Repeater 2> //Bound to a list in code behind
    <button/><button/>
</Repeater 2>
</UpdatePanel2>

<UpdatePanel3 UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Repeater 3> //Bound to a dataset in code behind
    <textbox/><button/><button/>
</Repeater 3>
<button/><button/><button/>
</UpdatePanel3>

<UpdatePanel4 UpdateMode="Conditional">
<panel 2>
   //Stuff
</panel 2>
    <Image/>
</UpdatePanel4>
```

Using in code behind

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ BindRepeater(); UpdatePanel2.Update(); }
```